# how to change value in text file to be date format

Tags: java, mysql

i new to mysql. i wanna ask something. i have a text file that contains information that saparated by "|" and end with whitespace. every line have specific date that put into string format. how should i chage the string to be full date format in mysql...

here is my text file

```
outletid|date|revcode|paymentmode|receiptnumbe|accnumber|amount|
6841|20110214|214|01|T00000067030010004032611|X700122260107|9730.80|
```

i use command like this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/intel/try.txt' INTO TABLE user_payment
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

how can i change that date column to be full date format in mysql? is it need to reprogramming first before load into mysql? if yes, how it done java programming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split each line with | then for converting date into MySQL date format, MySQL has DATE_FORMAT function.

as per your current example following is test code this may help you.

if you date column type is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", execute following Query and validate the date then using DATE_FORMAT function insert into DB

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( '20110214', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) AS date;
```

if column type is "YYYY-MM-DD"

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( '20110214', '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS date;
```

you can view below URL for more detail about MySQL Date_format function
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

PS: if this answer helps you please accept.

Answer (score 0):

If the column type is timestamp, date or datetime, it should be

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

e.g.

```
'2013-10-10 10:00:00'
```